# Can you load dynamic maps in the phonegap framework?

Tags: iphone, android, dictionary, cordova

Currently I've been using google's static maps to display maps in a phonegap app I'm developing. But I'm wondering if there's any way to load a google map that the user could scroll into and out of? I would want similar functionality as the maps app in most mobile environments. Is there any way to incorporate that type of service into my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is yes. You can write native code to do that and incorporate it with your PhoneGap app.

How you do it on various platforms is another question!

I have found that using Google Maps V3 in certain cases works pretty well too.

Answer (score 0):

there is some MapView code floating around the internet that will allow you to use the map.app on the phone to render pins and annotations.

i have modified the code for use in a prototype application i am writing